# Self Join on MySql table

Tags: php, mysql, join

So I a have some users in my database and each one of them is able to submit 'referrals' to our company.  I am creating a table which shows how many referrals each user has submitted from the current month and previous month so we can track if they are an active sales rep.  While I was successful in displaying the current month numbers for a given user, I have been having a hard time displaying the information from the previous month correctly.  I get the number of referrals from the previous month, but it gives me the same number for each of the users.

```
|=========|========|==========|=============|
|user_id   refer_id  referals      date     |
|-------------------------------------------|
|1             1     mcdonalds   2017-12-19 |
|1             2     Burger King 2017-12-19 |
|1             3     Wendys      2017-12-21 |
|1             4     Arby's      2017-12-22 |
|1             5     In n' out   2018-01-02 |
|2             6     Chipotle    2018-01-03
|2             7     Carl's jr.  2018-01-04 |
|===========================================|
```

User 1 should have 1 referral and user 2 should have 2 referrals for the current month, which indeed works, and User 1 should have 4 referrals for the previous month, however I am getting 4 returned for each user. I would also like to condense this down into one query, but I'm not sure what type of JOIN to use, or do I even need one?  I have found information on SELF JOINS and INNER JOIN and previous questions about it, but I'm not sure which to use in my case.

```
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Sales Name</th>
        <th>Current Month</th>
        <th>Previous Month</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php   
      //CURRENT MONTH QUERY 

      $query = "SELECT user_id, COUNT(refer_id) AS refer_total
                FROM table
                WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) GROUP BY user_id";
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 

      //PREVIOUS MONTH QUERY   

     $query2 = "SELECT user_id, COUNT(refer_id) AS previous_total
                 FROM table
                 WHERE 
                 YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
                 MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) GROUP BY user_id";     
     $total = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);          

     while($values = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total)) {    
       $previous = $values['previous_total'];
     }

     while($values = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
       $user_id = $values['user_id'];
       $num_refer = $values['refer_total'];
       echo "<tr><td>$user_id</td><td>$num_refer</td><td>$previous</td></tr>";
     }

     if(mysqli_num_rows < 5) {
       echo "Inactive!";
     }
  ?>
</table> <!--END TABLE-->
```

Comment: If your queries are giving the right result, that means you are traversing the query wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by the date as well using a date function. The only reason it appears as though the current month is correct in your results is because each user has 1 for the current month.

```
mysql> select user_id, date_format(date,'%Y-%m'), count(*) from test group by user_id, date_format(date,'%Y-%m');
+---------+---------------------------+----------+
| user_id | date_format(date,'%Y-%m') | count(*) |
+---------+---------------------------+----------+
|       1 | 2017-12                   |        4 |
|       1 | 2018-01                   |        1 |
|       2 | 2018-01                   |        1 |
+---------+---------------------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

actually i just realized that wasn't the format you were looking for. Something like the following should work:

```
mysql> select user_id, 
sum(case date_format(date,'%Y-%m') when date_format(curdate(),'%Y-%m') then 1 else 0 end) as current_month, 
sum(case date_format(date,'%Y-%m') when date_format(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m') then 1 else 0 end) as previous_month 
from test group by user_id;
+---------+---------------+----------------+
| user_id | current_month | previous_month |
+---------+---------------+----------------+
|       1 |             1 |              4 |
|       2 |             1 |              0 |
+---------+---------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I apologize, I had missed putting a row in my table.  User 1 has 1 referral for current month and user 2 has 2 referrals for current month.  When I group then by user_id it does give those numbers, but it does still give me 4 for each of the users even if I group them by user_id, date_format(date,'%Y-%m').

Comment: This worked absolutely fantastic! Thanks so much for helping! I'm not familiar with coding out the case so I'm going to do some more research on this so I understand it really well.

Comment: It is essentially an if ... else statement for mysql. I'm more familiar with Oracle sql and the equivalent there is DECODE. Here's a link to the docs for mysql CASE  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll read more into the case statements and do some research.  This really helps keeping everything clean and in one query.